# How can I use only integer parameters in package GA (Rstudio)

Tags: r, rstudio, genetic-algorithm

I need to use package 'GA' to create a genetic algorithm that allows to improve hyper-parameters of one search algorithm. 
Problems are :

1. The first problem is just that I don't know how I can use Integer value and not Real values.
2. The second problem, I don't know how I can limit the values to 2 choices (ex : 1 and 0).

The code is here :

```
popSize = 150

maxiter = 10

run = maxiter

pcrossover = 0.8

pmutation = 0.1 

elitism = max(1, round(popSize*0.05))

Rastrigin <- function(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7) {

 if (x6 <= 0.5) {

  if (x7 <= 0.5) {

   print("1")

   -(x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7) * 2

  } else {

   print("2")

   -(x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7) * 2 / 4

  }

 } else {

   if (x7 <= 0.5) {

      print("3")

      -(x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7) * 4

   } else {

    print("4")

    -(x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6+x7) * 4 / 4

  }

 }

}

     GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 

     fitness =  function(x) Rastrigin(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], as.integer(x[5]), x[6], x[7]),

     min = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), max = c(1, 1, 1, 10, 1000, 1, 1),

     popSize = popSize, maxiter = maxiter,  run = run, 

     pcrossover = pcrossover, pmutation = pmutation, elitism = elitism,

     optim = FALSE, 

     selection = gareal_tourSelection,

     population = gareal_Population,

     crossover = gareal_blxCrossover,

     mutation = gareal_rsMutation

     )
```

Sorry, it's my first post. I hope that I am understandable.

Thank you very for you help,

Maxime

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the first question. You seem not to want "integer" value, but rather "binary" value (that is either 0 or 1). In order to do that you need to specify the parameter "type" to "binary". In that case you would also need to set the parameter "nBits" to the number of values you would like to have. 
There is very good vignette for this package: https://luca-scr.github.io/GA/articles/GA.html